# Is 'Th.' in a name the short form of Theodor?

Tags: abbreviation, person-names

I have come across some occurrences of 'Dr. Th.' followed by a name. I first thought it means Doctor theologiae, but I am seeing it in contexts that have nothing to do with theology.

[Example](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkasso):

> Betriebswirtschaftlicher Verlag Dr. Th. Gabler, Gablers
>   Wirtschafts-Lexikon, Band 3, 1984, Sp. 2161

Is 'Th.' by any chance the short form of Theodor?

Answer (score 17):

**Th** as an abbreviation name can stand for many first names and is not explicitly intended for ONE first name. It can be for "Theodor", but it can also be "Thomas", "Thaddäus" or another first name that starts with "Th".

But in your example, however, it is "Theodor":

> Dr. Theodor Gabler als Betriebswirtschaftlicher Verlag Dr. Th. Gabler

Comment: Is it common to abbreviate a personal name to two letters, rather than a single initial?  Does it depend upon the name in question?

Comment: Usually you just write the **first letter** of the first name, e.g. *J.Doe* for *John Doe*. By *Christian* it is common to write **Chr.** as an abbreviation and by *Stefan* **St**. But there is no regulation.

Comment: This occasionally happens in dutch. I suspect it has to do with the 'th' being a single letter (Þ, the thorn) in various old germanic languages and scripts. This is also the source of "Ye olde shoppe", a mistransliteration of "Þe olde shoppe".

Comment: @AI0867: I don’t think it’s to do with thorn being a single letter, since it’s common for plenty of other letter-combinations which were never a single letter in any germanic scripts: *Chr.* for *Christian*, *Ph.* for *Philipp*, etc.

Comment: @AI0867 Though I find that old germanic roots are interesting, it is more obvious that are Greek transliterations. Since the Greek alphabet has distinct letters for t and th, same as the German *ch* is a Greek *x* (because they sound alike), it is common to those letters. Also, *ph* was used to transliterate the Greek's phi into Latin (and later into German) - for no reason, because there is no collision with another Greek letter sounding like *f*.

Comment: Multi-letter abbreviations of names for disambiguation were already very common among the Romans. (I assume that if a lot of your name-writing consists in chiseling them into hard stone, you develop an appreciation for abbreviations.) See [this list of Roman *praenomina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenomen), where we see abbreviations *Cn.* for *Gnaeus* (*C.* standing for *Gaius*), *Ti.* for *Tiberius* (*T.* standing for *Titus*) etc.

Comment: "The" was not spelled with thorn, it was spelled "ðe". ð is the voiced consonant, as in "this", while Þ denotes the voiceless sound, as in "thin".

Answer (score 11):

In your example it's indeed short for [Theodor Gabler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springer_Gabler).

*Doctor theologiae* is in short [Dr. theol.](https://www.uni-heidelberg.de/fakultaeten/theologie/studium/studiengaenge/promotion.html).

As @guidot pointed out in a comment: Any specification following *Dr.* is lower-case, as

- rer. nat.
- h.c.
- rer. pol.
- med.
- phil.

... etc.

Comment: Thanks @guidot - I added it into the answer.

Comment: "Any specification following Dr. is lower-case" That's not entirely true. There is the special unicorn of the "Dr.-Ing.".

Comment: @Maeher That's because unicorns don't speak Latin. ;)

Answer (score 10):

In Germany, the degree [Doctor theologiae](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_theologiae) is abbreviated as *Dr. theol.* Here, *Th.* abbreviates the given name of Dr. Gabler, which could be, for example

- Theodor
- Theodora
- Thomas
- Theolen
- Theobald
- Thaddeus / Thaddäus
- …